# Return to Merchant Website after PayPal Payment

Tags: php, paypal, return

I have a PHP form on my website, when the user clicks submit - they are redirected to a Booking Confirmation page. At this point, I have set up a PayPal connection (Sandbox) as follows;

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="youremail@email.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
        <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">

        <b>First name:</b><span style="padding-left:5em;"></span>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" style="width:20em;">
        <br><br>
        <b>Last name:</b><span style="padding-left:5.1em;"></span>
        <input type="text" name="last_name" style="width:20em;">
        <br>
        <b>Email Address:</b><span style="padding-left:3.35em;"></span>
        <input type="text" name="email" style="width:20em;">

        <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $randomString ?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.example.com/thank-you/">
        <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://www.example.com/my_ipn.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2"> 

        <?php 
        if (($Adults > 0) && ($Students > 0) && ($Children > 0))
        {
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name_1' value='" . $selectroute ." (Adult - " . $ticket .")'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount_1' value='15'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='quantity_1' value='" . $Adults . "'>";

            echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name_2' value='" . $selectroute ." (Student - " . $ticket .")'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount_2' value='15'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='quantity_2' value='" . $Students . "'>";

            echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name_3' value='" . $selectroute ." (Child - " . $ticket .")'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount_3' value='15'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='quantity_3' value='" . $Children . "'>";
        }
        elseif (($Adults > 0) && ($Students > 0))
        {
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name_1' value='" . $selectroute ." (Adult - " . $ticket .")'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount_1' value='15'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='quantity_1' value='" . $Adults . "'>";

            echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name_2' value='" . $selectroute ." (Student - " . $ticket .")'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount_2' value='15'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='quantity_2' value='" . $Students . "'>";
        }
        elseif (($Students > 0) && ($Children > 0))
        {
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name_1' value='" . $selectroute ." (Student - " . $ticket .")'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount_1' value='15'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='quantity_1' value='" . $Students . "'>";

            echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name_2' value='" . $selectroute ." (Child - " . $ticket .")'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount_2' value='15'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='quantity_2' value='" . $Children . "'>";
        }
        elseif (($Adults > 0) && ($Children > 0))
        {
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name_1' value='" . $selectroute ." (Adult - " . $ticket .")'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount_1' value='15'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='quantity_1' value='" . $Adults . "'>";

            echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name_2' value='" . $selectroute ." (Child - " . $ticket .")'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount_2' value='15'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='quantity_2' value='" . $Children . "'>";
        }
        elseif ($Adults > 0)
        {
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name_1' value='" . $selectroute ." (Adult - " . $ticket .")'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount_1' value='15'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='quantity_1' value='" . $Adults . "'>";
        }
        elseif ($Students > 0)
        {
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name_1' value='" . $selectroute ." (Student - " . $ticket .")'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount_1' value='15'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='quantity_1' value='" . $Students . "'>";
        }
        elseif ($Children > 0)
        {
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name_1' value='" . $selectroute ." (Child - " . $ticket .")'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount_1' value='15'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='quantity_1' value='" . $Children . "'>";
        }
        ?>

        <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/btn/btn_paynow_cc_144x47.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" style="position:relative; top: 8em; padding-left:15em;">
        <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
```

The above form takes the values that the user entered on the PHP booking form and displays them in the Order Summary section of Paypal, as expected. I can then login as the buyer and make a payment. I then want to be returned to the http://www.example.com/thank-you/ but instead I am landed on a PayPal page which states the Transaction ID and confirmation that the payment has been processed.

How do I return to the Thank You page on the Merchant website rather than on the PayPal website?

I have Auto-Return turned on, and a Return URL set. As you can see above, I have specified the return and rm variables but no luck.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the  `return` does that, ar eyou sure its set properly?

Comment: I have looked at so many examples and I can't see what I am doing wrong as the "return" variable and the "rm" variable seem to be what I need to use for this to work but no luck even when using them. I think it is set properly - can you see anything I might have done wrong above?

Comment: i see noting obvious, try another browser\computer

Comment: It really sounds to me like you actually don't have auto-return enabled like you think you do.  Remember that would need to be done in the sandbox seller account that you're using.  The return URL value just populates the link that PayPal page that says "Return to merchant..." but auto-return would do that automatically within 10 seconds.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that even when you get Auto-Return enabled and working there is still no guarantee the user will make it back to the return URL.  They could close the browser before the redirect happens, for example.  You'll want to make sure any post-payment processing that needs to get done is happening in your IPN script.  You may also want to look into the Express Checkout API, which would guarantee that the user always ends up at your site to finish things off.

Comment: I have doubled checked that Auto Return is enabled in the seller account, but still no luck. I will post a solution if I find one :( Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

At long last - I got it working.

Bit of a silly mistake - but just in case anyone else experiences this problem - I had left the business email in the code as youremail@email.com as shown above.

Once I changed the business variable value to the merchant email address - it worked!